# How to start performance testing

Tags: performance, testing, load

I have taken as an example for learning and gathered some information about tools, objectives,scenarios, but I need your inputs. Please assist me.

I am new to Performance testing and would like to test the following website [www.volkswagen.co.nz](http://www.volkswagen.co.nz)

Can you tell me, what are need to be tested? What are the scenarios and activities for each scenario?  What metrics do I need to add? Which is the best and free tool for testing it? How to test if it is deployed in cloud like AWS?

Please let me know, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Performance testing needs,

1. Identify critical/heavy/important scenario in your webapp (irrespective of deployment cloud/standalone)
2. Identify service level agreements in terms of response times, throughput, latency etc.
3. Identify workload model i.e. how much user load application is expecting. this should be as fine grained as possible (avg users per transaction/workflow at a point of time)
4. Identify tools (JMeter is freeware and best but if you can afford paid then look at loadrunner, neoload etc.)
5. Record the script for workflows and parameterise and correlate.
6. generate test setup for load test and execute the load test.
7. monitor system utilization, collect metrics like response time, throughput, error rate, latency etc.

This all comes in load testing. For more you can read http://www.guru99.com/performance-testing.html

Answer (score 0):

> I am new to Performance testing and would like to test the following website www.volkswagen.co.nz

That is a recipe for disaster.  No one new should be allowed to work on their own without a full period of training and internship with a master in the field.  This is true of stone masons, electricians, plumbers, barbers, accountants, engineers and physicians.  And it is most certainly true of performance testers/engineers.

There are dozens of foundation skills you need to master before you touch any tool, open source or otherwise.  Until you show mastery of those items along with tool mechanics for your tool you should not be allowed to test any website, particularly a production website.  And, if you don't work for this company what you are engaging in is a denial of service attack and could leave you with exposed legal liability.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly agree with James on this one. 
Do not touched the site if:

- it's not yours
- not sure what you are doing
- the owner gave you explicit (and sounds like irresponsible) permission
- don't know or don't have the support to restore the environment into a working state

If you do work  for the company then you need to have a test environment first, a playground where you can mess around and nobody would mind if you take it down.

- Firstly get information from the business on which use cases needs to
  be tested.
- Get response times target for user actions and for environments utilisation.
- Get response time targets for environments utilisation: define environment monitoring tactics.
- Found a tool that can fit for purpose: Jmeter, Gattling,etc, lot's of free ones available.
- Get a test environment, preferably similar scale to production
- Create scripts to cover critical use cases
- Comply scripts into scenarios
- Create a reporting framework
- Kick off monitoring
- Kick off scenario
- Collect and analyse results

Be mindful of the free editions of load testing tools: they tend to be easy to use at first but soon as you start to outgrow it it can cost a fortune and more often then not it's hard to port scripts/scenarios to another tool.